# RegularExpressionValidator to not contain any spaces as well as any of the following characters `~!@#$%^&*()=+[]{}\|;:'",<>/?_ with specific length

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am trying to implement this rule with regex : "The name at asp:textbox that is given as input by a user must not contain any spaces as well as any of the following characters:"

```
`~!@#$%^&*()=+[]{}\|;:'",<>/?_ .
```

And also the length must **not** be greater than 15.

I am using something like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validateName" runat="server" Text="*" ValidationExpression="(?=^.{1,15}$)(^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$)" ControlToValidate="txtName" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Wizard"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**BUT** the problem is that **test12.** is not valid (right) and **test12.test.something** is passing, which is not right for my issue.
Also I tried this regex without result as asdasdads.gr passes (not right):

```
(?=^[A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,15}$)
```

Maybe I made it too complicated and now I am getting stuck.

Comment: They are the characters which aren't allowed, I'm trying to get an idea of the other chars allowed. Can you not just select what you need rather than what not to have allowed? [A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,15}

Comment: xmm!maybe this is a good idea! But what about the spaces?

Comment: @JoshLeeDucks I tried (?=^[A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,15}$) whithout a result!Help me :)

Comment: do you need the full stop? you said that "test12." is not valid? it has a full stop? and you said you didn't want to allow full stops?

Comment: I overlooked the 15 char long requirement. Try [`^[^\][^\`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\|;:'",<>/?_\s.]{1,15}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xU5aB3/3). Or if the ``\`` must be doubled, use `^[^\\][^\`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\\\|;:'",<>/?_\s.]{1,15}$`.

Comment: @GiannisGrivas, where did you get that original regex?  It's much more specific than your stated requirements, and it explicitly allows periods (`.`).  If we ignore that and just go by the first two paragraphs of your question, the regex practically writes itself: ``@"^[^][`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\|;:'"",<>/?_.\s]{1,15}$"``.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finaly this worked for me:

```
ValidationExpression="^[^\][^`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\|;:'\x22,<>/?_\s.]{1,15}$"
```

Full code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHostname" runat="server" CssClass="NormalTextBox" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HostnameValidator" runat="server" Text="*" Display="Dynamic"
             ControlToValidate="txtHostname" meta:resourcekey="HostnameValidator" SetFocusOnError="true"
             ValidationGroup="VpsWizard">
         *
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valCorrectHostname" runat="server" Text="*" meta:resourcekey="valCorrectHostname"
             ValidationExpression="^[^\][^`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\|;:'\x22,<>/?_\s.]{1,15}$"
             ControlToValidate="txtHostname" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="VpsWizard">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: You did not have to post your own answer since my regex really worked for you. Please consider accepting my answer. Note that you can actually use `&quot;` instead of a `"` in a regex.

Comment: Although you did not answer right at the begging I asked you to add the escaped version and you did it 9 hours before, I will accept your answer.I only post my solution to help others. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: But it is my regex you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Since your requirements are:

> - No characters from this set: `` `~!@#$%^&*()=+[]{}\|;:'",<>/?_ . ``
> - And also the length must not be greater than 15.

You may just use a negated character class with `{1,15}` limiting quantifier:

```
ValidationExpression="^[^\][^`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\|;:'&quot;,<>/?_\s.]{1,15}$"
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU5aB3/3).  We must escape the `\` symbol and we need to escape the `]` symbol (as it can be used by JS engine). Since the `\` is used to specify escape sequences, escape it, too (use double slashes to denote one literal `\`). **Note you need to serialzie the double quote as `&quot;` (or use a hex representation for a regex - `\x22`) if you are using it inside some HTML attribute.**

**Detailed explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `` [^\][^`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\|;:'&quot;,<>/?_\s.]{1,15} `` - 1 to 15 characters (due to the limiting quantifier `{1,15}`) that are not in the defined set (a `[^...]` is a *negated character class*). If you plan to allow empty string, use `{0,15}` quantifier.
- `$` - end of string

Comment: I tried     ValidationExpression="^[^\][^`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\|;:'",<>/?_\s.]{1,15}$" <asp:RegularExpressionValidator  but not working , .Please try it

Comment: You need to escape the `]` inside the `[...]` since it is used by JS (for client side validation). See my [demo of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/xU5aB3/3). Use `^[^\\][^\`~!@#$%^&*()=+{}\\\\|;:'\",<>/?_\\s.]{1,15}$`. I guess the quote mark should be just escaped once for the expression to be valid in the code.

Comment: please update your answer with the escaped quote mark version.thanks

Comment: I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments we discussed trying only searching for valid characters.

`[A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,15}`

This should work for "test12" if you need "test12." just add the full stop in there. Also \d is for digits instead of using 0-9

`[A-Za-z\d\-\.]{1,15}`

if you want to allow it to have an optional full top at the end use the following regex. The ? means 0 or 1.

`[A-Za-z\d\-]{1,15}\.?`

Comment: Not working.Look I want to have mixed numbers and letters and not the special characters I wrote (in everywhere) and the length not to overcome 15

Comment: but this one asdasddas/ ?! I dont want this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100135/discussion-between-joshleeducks-and-giannis-grivas).